# Django regex url parsing to calling wrong view

Tags: python, regex, django, api, django-rest-framework

I have a `Django 2.2` project (using the rest framework) where I need to call a view function with a url of the following format:

```
/class/students?date=07092019`
```

and I've set up the following url route to handle this url:

```
re_path(r'^class/students%3Fdate%3D(?P<date>\w+)/$',StudentsInClassView.as_view() ,name='student')
```

The corresponding view function has the following definition:

```
class StudentsInClassView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, date,format=None):
```

For some reason, whenever I go to url, it gets converted to

```
/class/students/?date=07092019
```

and a different view, with the URL

```
path('class/students/',StudentsView.as_view() ,name='students')
```

gets called instead.

If I remove the `?date=` from the URL and just include the actual date, the `StudentsInClassView` is called as expected. I've escaped both the question mark and the equal sign but doing so doesn't seem to make a difference.

How can I get the `?date=` slug to remain in the URL as it is used to call the StudentsInClassView? Is there a different regex that could be used to match the whole URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The part after `?` mark is called [**`URL Query String`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). You shouldn't include it in the regex. Instead either you can change the url to `/class/students/<str:date>/` or You can put some logic to throw errors in the View if there is no `date`(But I don't think that would be an ideal solution as URL querystrings are not mandatory part of an URL):

```
class StudentsView(...):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not 'date' in request.GET:
            raise HttpResponse("provide date", status=400)
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: So changing the url to `/class/students/<str:date>/` will still allow for the view to be called from the browser with `/class/students?date=07092019` (assuming that you check for the presence of the date as done above)?

Comment: No, you will need to call '/class/student/15102019/'

Comment: Ok, I got your version of the view to work (getting the date from the request dict) but only by changing a character in the path name to differentiate between the two versions of `class/students/`. How can I force the 'student' url to be called instead of the 'student***s***' view when the `/class/students/<str:date>/` is used even though the two urls have the same base url?

Comment: When writing the urls in urls.py, you need to put `/class/students/<str:date>/` before `/class/students/`, then django will take care of the rest.

Comment: To get the date to be passed to the keyword arguments dict, I didn't include `<str:date>` and instead used `/class/studentz/`, using the 'z' to differentiate between the urls. The date won't be passed to `**kwargs**` if `<str:date>` is used right?

Comment: Actually, I could probably just have one url and one view for both use cases and then just switch between the logic for each one based on the presence of the `date` in the `**kwargs` dict.

Comment: Well you can approach like this. Have single view `/class/students/` and use it for both purposes. if someone calls with `/class/students/?date=12122019` then do the operations(like filtering or stuff) based on the value `request.GET['date']`